# SQL Server: Hierarchical query with depth

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to show employee and his manager name with depth.

If Simon is top manager and Katie's manager is Simon and John's manager is Katie, then Simon's level would be 0 because he is top and Katie's level will be 1 and John's level will be 2.

I tried below way but not getting desired output. Please tell me what to rectify in code.

My code:

```
Declare @ID INT
SET @ID = 6;

WITH EmployeeCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ID, Name, MgrID, 0 AS level 
    FROM 
        Employee
    WHERE 
        ID = @ID

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        emp.ID, emp.Name, emp.MgrID, level+1 AS level 
    FROM 
        Employee emp
    JOIN 
        EmployeeCTE ON emp.ID = EmployeeCTE.MgrID
)
--select * from EmployeeCTE
SELECT 
    e1.Name, ISNULL(e2.Name, 'Top BOSS') as [Manager Name], 
    e2.level 
FROM
    EmployeeCTE e1 
LEFT JOIN 
    EmployeeCTE e2 ON e1.MgrID = e2.ID
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is Node-to-Top, notice in the final select [Level]

```
;WITH EmployeeCTE AS
(
    Select ID,Name,MgrID, 0 as level FROM @Employee
    WHERE ID=3
    UNION ALL
    Select r.ID,r.Name,r.MgrID, level+1 as level 
    FROM @Employee r
    JOIN EmployeeCTE p on r.ID = p.MgrID
)
Select e1.Name
      ,ISNULL(e2.Name,'Top BOSS') as [Manager Name]
      ,row_number() over (order by e1.level  desc) as [Level]
 from EmployeeCTE e1 
 left join EmployeeCTE e2 on e1.MgrID=e2.ID
```

Returns

```
Name    Manager Name    Level
Simon   Top BOSS        1
Katie   Simon           2
John    Katie           3
```

Comment: @Mou Just for fun, include e1.level in your final select.  You will see that the FIRST node you fetched is level 0, and then (as you go up the hierarchy) the level increases.  So to dynamically correct that, we just get the reversed sequence  ... thus the descending order